Offset left value of inline element containing multiline string
Context
I'm trying to get the offset left value (in pixels) of a multiline text div in  display: inline
The problem
To achieve this i'm currently using the element.offsetLeft value. But this value give me the offsetLeft value of the first line of my multiline div. But what i want is the offsetleft value of the entire div. What i mean is that the first line can start at any left value based on where the previous inline div text ends.
The question
Is there any way to get that offsetLeft value ? (I can't use boundingBoxes methodes because i'm not working in the window landmark i will not extend myself on why but consider that i can't use boundingBoxes functions.).
Exemple

In this picture you can see a wrap div in grey which is in display: block. Classic. Then you can see two display: inline div containing the same text. Each can be differanciated because of the color of the text.
And the problem is that when i use element.offsetLeft on the "red div" i get the offset left of the first line that nearly start in the middle of the wrap div when i want the offsetLeft of the entire inline div which can be see on the second line of the red text (which is 0 in this exemple).
Thank for the time spent to answer and do not hesitate to ask for precisions even if the probleme is pretty straight forward.
Edit 1
So to give a bit more context. I'm working since 3 years on a new Ui UX Design software. That means that this software has a 2D view in which you can "move a virtual camera" managed with basic translate3D and scale transforms. Every elements can be rotated in its parent and i actually handle the exact coordinates of each element with DOMMatrix multiplications. So in fact the grey div i showed in my exemple can be 1 or 10 degres deep in the element arborescence or even more and the "root div" which can be the entry point of the "canva" can be scaled.
The transformation accumulation make it really complicated to use native boundingBoxes functions that why i said what i said (... " i can't use boudingBoxes functions" ) and it also isn't straight forward in a process where everything in calculated using DOMMatrix.
Everything really is complicated that why my question is that simple. The probleme exactly is what i ask for, no need to more context because an answer to "how to get the left offset value of an inline div containing multiline string in a display:block div" as all i need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects is the correct method, and I doubt there is an alternative. What do you mean by "i'm not working in the window landmark"?

Perhaps include your actual attempt so we can help you fix it.

I made an edit to give more context. There is no "actual attempt" as i said i'm normally using offsetLeft on an element to get its left offset value but in case of a multiline text inline div it's not working "as expected" i would say. That is why i'm asking if there is a way to achieve it properly.

@Xeyes Can't you just get the offset of your parent? (+padding, I suppose). Wouldn't that be the same number?

That is what i was thinking at the begining but that won't work in the case where the text is aligned in center. And even if this isn't the case the text can potentially be in just one line and in this case it will not be the parent offset + padding and i don't have any way to know if my inline div is rendered in  amultiline or single line string

Maybe get both. If they're not equal, and the height of the span is bigger than your line-height (Say, 1.5em) then you know it's multi-line, and therefore you need the the parent's offset. (I'm 95% certain multi-line content is always effectively 100% of the width of the parent, even if text-align:center causes it to wrap weirdly.)

This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822969/positioning-a-absolute-div-at-the-edges-of-an-inline-span

Yeah to know if it's multiline i agree that this is the easiest method but as i said text can be aligned at start, center, justify etc .. So that won't work anyway. I checked the stack post, it's not really relevant unfortunately because he manage to get the start position of the first line and end position of the last line. What i need is the left offset of the leftmost line of the multiline or single line inline div content..

That's what I meant. If it's not more than one line, take it as normal, the way @jakubpodhaisky posted. If it IS more than one line, then you know your span is guaranteed to be width:100%;, and therefore the text-align doesn't matter, because it'll have width:100% and therefore it'll always have an offset equal to the parent............... No. Damn. I'm wrong. Holy cow, text-align:right; makes things, uh, real difficult.

Yeah.. It really is a tricky question, i did not think at the begining that it would be so difficult to achieve this. I'm kinda clueless

You are looking to get the offset of the bounding rectangle of the element. You can access it via the getBoundingClientRect method, however that is relative to the viewport not to the offsetParent element like offsetLeft. You can however simply subtract their respective .left values, and also take int account scroll offsets, to get the desired value:


function boundingOffsetLeft(element) {
  const {
    offsetParent
  } = element;
  let offset = element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  if (offsetParent) {
    offset -= offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  }
  while (element = element.parentElement) {
    offset += element.scrollLeft;
    if (element === offsetParent) break;
  }
  return offset;
}

const normalText = document.getElementById('normal');
const redText = document.getElementById('red');
const scrollArea = document.getElementById('scroll');

const normalResult = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
const redResult = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

scrollArea.onscroll = () => {
  normalResult.textContent = `Normal: ${boundingOffsetLeft(normalText)}px`;
  redResult.textContent = `Red: ${boundingOffsetLeft(redText)}px`;
};
scrollArea.onscroll();
#scroll {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #aaa;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#red {
  color: #f00;
}
<div id="scroll">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span id="normal">Text qui peut varier mais c'est juste un test en fait voila.</span>
      <span id="red">Text qui peut varier mais c'est juste un test en fait voila.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I think it would be how i would have done that in a "standard context". But actually as i said in my first edit, elements can be rotated using rotate transform. And the getBoundingClientRect return a boundingbox rect containing the rotated element after the transform being applied.. So that's a real problem because if the grey rectangle is rotated then boxes will not reflect the real top left coords of the element..

Then I doubt there is anything you can do other than shadow-mounting invisible clones of the elements in a non-rotated container of the same dimensions to get the would-be offsets from there

Yeah i'll maybe have to clone it then do the bboxes substraction.. Okay i think this will be the best solution anyway i don't think as you mentionned that it will be something more straight forward or simple than that. I'll wait to see if an idea coming from nowhere can make some improvement in the other case i'll give u the bounty

offsetLeft is relative to the first positioned (not static) ancestor container.
you can create an invisible dummy element that is added to the document at the same hierarchical level as your multiline text. You would ensure that this element has the same styles applied as your text container (except for text content, of course), and then measure its offsetLeft to get the position of the multiline container relative to its positioned ancestor.


<style>
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee; 
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .inline-text {
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
  }

  .inline-text.red {
    display: inline;
    color: #f00;
  }
  
  .dummy {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: inline;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="normal-text" class="inline-text">
    Text qui peut varier mais c'est juste un test en fait voila.
  </div>
  <div id="red-text" class="inline-text red">
    Text qui peut varier mais c'est juste un test en fait voila.
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function calculateOffsetLeft(element) {
    var dummyElement = document.createElement('div');
    dummyElement.classList.add('dummy');
    
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(dummyElement, element);
    
    var offsetLeftValue = dummyElement.offsetLeft;
    dummyElement.parentNode.removeChild(dummyElement);
    
    return offsetLeftValue;
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var normalTextElement = document.getElementById('normal-text');
    var redTextElement = document.getElementById('red-text');

    var normalOffsetLeft = calculateOffsetLeft(normalTextElement);
    var redOffsetLeft = calculateOffsetLeft(redTextElement);

    console.log('Normal Text Offset Left:', normalOffsetLeft);
    console.log('Red Text Offset Left:', redOffsetLeft);
    
    // Display the offsetLeft values on the page for demonstration purposes.
    var normalResultDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var redResultDiv = document.createElement('div');
    
    normalResultDiv.textContent = 'Normal Text Offset Left: ' + normalOffsetLeft + 'px';
    redResultDiv.textContent = 'Red Text Offset Left: ' + redOffsetLeft + 'px';
    
    document.body.appendChild(normalResultDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(redResultDiv);
  };
</script>

</body>
</html>




Yeah you are exactly doing what i do not want to do. With this exemple the red text offset left is 138 when i expect it to be 18 because the smallest bounding boxes of the multiline left offset is in fact 18 and not 138... So i want to find a way to get 18 as left offset value for the inline div

I dont think I get what you need to do...
You want the red text to start on the new line so the offset left is 18 ?
Or do you want to generate a dummy on a new line so that the offset you get from the calculation is 18 even tho the real offset is 138 ?@Xeyes

My exemple can't be more clear. It's like you literally wrote the code generating my exemple perfectly. Now take your exemple and consider the smallest rectangle that fully contains the red text. What its offset left value will be ? it will be 18 not 138 ! And that the value i want, i want to get 18 but actually the element.offsetLeft value give me 138 but 138 only is the offsetLeft value of the first line of the text when i want the left offset value of the entire div which is 18.

And i don't understand the point of using a dummy element when you can just do document.getElementById('red-text').offsetLeeft to get 138

@jakubpodhaisky He's trying to get the offset of the word c'est, in your example. Even if he has text-align:center.
